# Use 'on message' to find message in .byte(1) in CAPL

Tags: can-bus, capl, canoe

I need to find for example the message 0x02 for byte(1) in the bus.

When I use

```
on message 0x02
{
}
```

Is it like?

```
on message *
{
   if(this.id==0x02)
   {
   }
}
```

How can I then use on message for `.byte(1)`?

Answer (score 1):

Your second piece of code is the right way to go.

```
on message *
{
   if(this.id == 0x02)
   {
      write("%x", this.byte(1));
   }
}
```

As shown above, you can use `.byte(1)` even for the `this` keyword.

Comment: No i meant i wanted to use the first method and search for the second byte instead of the id. I need the on message * method to read the response after that.

Comment: Are you working on diagnostics?
To answer your question, you can also use `this.byte(1)` in the first method.